# Password Protected Excel File

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel spreadsheet that is password-protected. I need to open this spreadsheet and read the data from it. I've been attempting to use the POI API to no avail. A Java solution would be preferred but any ideas would be helpful.

Edit:  Yes, I have the password. The file is password protected in excel; a password must be entered to view the spreadsheet.

Edit2: I am unable to open it with POI with the password, I am looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you actually have the password and just having problems transmitting it to POI. It also seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204382/how-can-we-read-protected-password-excel-file-xls-with-poi-api

Comment: Excel has several protection mechanisms where a password is used. Are you referring to the file-protection, allowing the file to be opened only with the supplied password?

Comment: See edits regarding questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).

It has been a while since I have done this, so I may not be telling you how to do it correctly, but there is definitely a way to do this using JExcelApi. Try the source below:

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("/path/to/protected.xls"));
workbook.setProtected(false);
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("/path/to/unprotected.xls"), workbook);
WritableSheet[] sheets = copy.getSheets();

for (WritableSheet sheet : sheets){
    sheet.getSettings().setProtected(false);
}

copy.write();
copy.close();
```

Of course, you will need to import necessary classes and catch necessary exceptions.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Is there any method to set password on excel??

Comment: I tried this but I am not able to set the password.Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256259/how-to-set-password-on-workbook-worksheet-of-excel-in-java-using-jexcel-api

Comment: why you are copying protected file into unprotected one, is it the only option? i'd like to avoid creating any new files, even temporarily.. assuming i have a password and i need just to read the data from the file - can it be done in jxl without this weird copying..?

Comment: @Kevin Crowell What is the filetype of this file?

Comment: @ApoloRadomer The example is for an excel file (xls) but xlsx would be the same.

Comment: @KevinCrowell I was talking about the script actually.

Comment: @KevinCrowell I was not able to load JExcelApi and make the JS run on my server. I want to visit a link on wamp that will remove the password from an xlsx file. It did not work with PHP and PHPExcel. I cannot include MACRO in my PHP script it make it work. Only JS can help it I guess. But I am pretty stuck.

Answer (score 7):

POI should be able to open both protected xls files (using *org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypt*) and protected xlsx files (using *org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt*). Have you tried these?

If you're using HSSF (for a xls file), you need to set the password before opening the file. You do this with a call to:

```
 org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypto.Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(password);
```

After that, HSSF should be able to open your file.

For XSSF, you want something like:

```
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("protect.xlsx"));
    EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
    Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
    d.verifyPassword(Decryptor.DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(d.getDataStream(fs));
```

Full details are given on the [POI Encryption documentation page](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html)

Comment: This looks most correct for POI. EncryptionInfo was introduced in POI in v3.7 or v3.8

Comment: how to set password on the unprotected excel file? Is there any method in this org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypto.Biff8EncryptionKey package

Comment: I think you need to use `Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);` instead in line #3

Comment: @HoomanYar Whoops, perils of copying from the unit tests which are in the same package! Thanks, now fixed

Comment: @Gagravarr I have never used this and I am not familiar with this. So, how can I replicate it in a few words? Create a specific file (filetype??) that has this script in it and run it in my server? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

addthe excel file in ODBC Sources (from control panel->Administrative Tools) and then execute the code:

```
// program to extract data from excel file

import java.sql.Connection ;
import java.sql.Statement  ;
import java.sql.ResultSet  ;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData ;
import java.sql.DriverManager ;
import java.sql.SQLException ;

public class ExtractExcelData {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,userName,password);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            System.err.println("unable to load excel  driver");
            return  ;
        }
        catch (SQLException se) {
            System.err.println("cannot connect to excel file");
            return  ;
        }

        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String select = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(select);
            metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

            int count = metaData.getColumnCount();
            while ( resultSet.next() ) {

                String col1 =  resultSet.getString(1) ; 
                String col2 =  resultSet.getString(2) ; 
                String col3 =  resultSet.getString(3) ; 

                System.out.println( col1 ) ;
                System.out.println( col2 ) ;
                System.out.println( col3 ) ;

                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException se) {
            System.err.println("cannot execute query");
            return ;
        }

        try {
            statement.close();
            resultSet.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException se ) {
            System.err.println("unable to close excel file");
            return  ;
        }
    }

    private static final String userName = "" ;
    private static final String password = "" ;
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:odbc:testexcel" ;
    private static final String DRIVER = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" ;

    private static Connection connection ;
    private static Statement statement ;
    private static ResultSet resultSet ;
    private static ResultSetMetaData metaData ;
}
```

Comment: This Windows only solution can't be recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to set password for excel file from java script, this script will only work on IE and Excel get should installed in the client system.

```
<script>
function setPasswordToExcel(password,excelFileName,newFileName)
{
   var Excel;
    Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
    Excel.Visible = false;
    var obj = Excel.Workbooks.Open(excelFileName);
    obj.Password =password;
    obj.SaveAs(newFileName);
    obj.Close();
    Excel.Close();
    return 1;
}       
 setPasswordToExcel("stephen","C:/test1.xls","C:\\test2.xls");
</script>
```