# How to read and edit a password protected workbook using jxl

Tags: java, excel, jxl

How can I programmatically check if a workbook of an excel file is password protected? If protected, how can I read and edit it using jxl?

For background, I wanted to make a file password protected but could not find a method to do it using jxl so I used `com.jexcel.util.ExcelAdapter`. That set a password on excel file,but I could not find a way to unprotect file for reading and editing.

Using jxl if I set a password on sheet then I can read it but I do not know how to set password on workbook and how to unlock the password. There is that method `isProtected()` that just tells that it is protected but I am unsure how to unlock and open it.

Comment: @Lucifer I am using jxl, I wanted to make file password protected but could not find a method to do it using jxl so I used "com.jexcel.util.ExcelAdapter" that set a password on excel file...but could not find a way to unprotect file for reading and editing...Using jxl if I set a password on sheet than i can read it but I do not know how to set password on workbook and how to unlock the password..there is that method "isProtected()" that just tell that it is protected but how can I open it....

Comment: Check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609301/password-protected-excel-file

Comment: this link is helpful for working with sheets using jxl. I was looking for workbook...but now I know it can not be done by the api that I'm using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using jexcelapi_2_6_12, a workbook can only be protected by using

workbook.setProtected(true);

It can be read and edited without making it unprotected. We can not set a password on woorkbook. If a woorkbook is already password protected then by catching "PasswordException" user can be notified to remove password.

Comment: only sheets can be password protected. These can be read/edited even  without giving a password.

Comment: I can't seem to find setProtected method in 2.6.12 API.