# Can we Update row and column of password protected excel sheet using java?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

```
NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File("C://Users//RK5026051//Downloads//500_Lanes.xls"));
        EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
        Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
        if (d.verifyPassword("manh.com")) {
           HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(d.getDataStream(fs));
        } else {
           System.out.println("wrong password");
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

Error--

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: no such entry: "EncryptionInfo", had: [_VBA_PROJECT_CUR, SummaryInformation, DocumentSummaryInformation, Workbook]
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode.getEntry(DirectoryNode.java:370)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode.createDocumentInputStream(DirectoryNode.java:177)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.<init>(EncryptionInfo.java:51)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.<init>(EncryptionInfo.java:47)
    at auto.excel.main(excel.java:15)
```

I am downloading a file from a application using selenium , I need to update some fields in the excel file and then upload it again.**

I know the password of the excel file i am downloading , Now i need to write a code so that it updates specific rows and columns , But I am unable to any operation on that excel file and i guess that is because its password protected .

I have tried some answers on stack Overflow but i is not working. Also i did not get many materials on internet about this topic.
Here is a sample code i tried

```
NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File("D://protectedfile.xlsx"));
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
if (d.verifyPassword("password")) {
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(d.getDataStream(fs));
} else {
   // Password is wrong
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994772/read-password-protected-excel-file-xlsx-using-java

Comment: you don't mention where your code fails?I mean, does `verifyPassword` block executed or `else`?

Comment: What kind of file is it you're trying to open? A `.xls` or a `.xlsx`? (They're different!)

Comment: its a xls file. is there a way we can un-protect a sheet by java code?

Answer (score 1):

First up, I know it isn't trendy these days, but you should [really really read the Apache POI documentation on reading protected files](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html). From that, you'll see that you're trying to use the `XLSX` decryption method for a protected `XLS` file, which unsurprisingly won't work!

However, there's an even easier way to go - [WorkbookFactory can take the password of your spreadsheet](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) when opening

So, just change your code to the very simple:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("protected.xls"), "password", true);
```

That will open the workbook in read-only mode, using the supplied password to read it, and identifying the required type automatically for you