# Java to open xlsx that needs password to open as well as needs password to edit

Tags: java, apache-poi

My situation is a bit awkward, I have .xlsx file that:
step 1. needs to enter password to open the file
step 2. needs to enter password to edit the file

now the code in this link: [Read Password protected excel file(.xlsx) using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994772/read-password-protected-excel-file-xlsx-using-java) is able to open the file with password in step 1, but I am not able to find a way to perform step 2 in java, thus my code throws exception. does anyone know how to perform step 2 in java by using org.apache.poi.

I have tested to remove the "password to edit" xlsx and just had password to open the xlsx, it worked as expected.

Anyways, below are the exceptions when i executed my code:
[Exceptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7XeP.png)

Comment: the exception stack trace does help - your document is in strict ooxml format and POI does not support that format -

Comment: first of all thanks to reply PJ Fanning, but as i stated in my post if I get rid of the password to edit, the code works as expected, the issue in here is the "password to edit" causing so much drama. if the POI doesn't support such format, then why it works if i get rid of "Password to edit".