# How to read password protected .xls file in java?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls

I have a code which reads a protected excel in `java`, but that code gives me error.
My java code.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.Decryptor;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class REadProtectedExcel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fname = "D:/Vijay/BRS_docs/10168/20.11.2014/20.11.2014/JCR_30.12.14_I Pay.xls";
        try {
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fname));
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
            Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
            if (d.verifyPassword("vijay")) {
                System.out.println("Password correct");
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fname);
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();
                while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
                    HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                    Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                    while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                        String cellvalue = "";
                        HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                        if (myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            cellvalue = myCell.getStringCellValue();
                        } else if (myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                            cellvalue = "" + myCell.getNumericCellValue();
                        } else if (myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                            cellvalue = "" + myCell.getBooleanCellValue();
                        } else if (myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                            cellvalue = "" + myCell.getCellFormula();
                        } else if (myCell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                            cellvalue = "";
                        }
                        System.out.println("cellvalue--" + cellvalue);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Password wrong");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**This code gives me following error.**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: no such entry: "EncryptionInfo"
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode.getEntry(DirectoryNode.java:375)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode.createDocumentInputStream(DirectoryNode.java:177)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.<init>(EncryptionInfo.java:45)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.EncryptionInfo.<init>(EncryptionInfo.java:39)
    at com.test.arrayList.REadProtectedExcel.main(REadProtectedExcel.java:22)
```

- I am using poi3.9 jar,xmlbeans-2.3.0jar,poi-ooml-3.6
- I am not getting the issue.Thanks in advance.
- Or Please share another way to read the .xls file.

Comment: Have you tried with xlsx? Is xls a hard requirement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Password Protected Excel File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609301/password-protected-excel-file) and look for second answer for poi

Comment: that second answer not working .

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI [provides documentation on Encryption on the website](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html). If you go to the [Apache POI homepage](http://poi.apache.org/) and look near the top of the menu on the left, you'll find it linked under [Encryption Support](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html). I would strongly suggest you read it!

As you'll then see, the code you have written is for Encrypted `.xlsx` files, which use a very different way of protecting the file to the older `.xls` files

As the docs explain, for password protected `.xls` files, all you need to do is something like:

```
String myPassword = "password";
org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypto.Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(myPassword);
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
```