# Is protecting Spreadsheet(MS Excel file) with password secure enough?

Tags: excel, security, encryption, spreadsheet

Is protecting Spreadsheet(MS Excel file) with password secure enough?

```
I can protect excel spreadsheet with two different passwords.
1. read only 
2. write/Edit
```

Is it secure enough? Can anyone having the spreadsheet read the file contents without passwords?

Comment: Thanks for reply. There was multiple questions around excel in stackoverflow, but I couldn't get exact reply on security aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to see the contents of the file without knowing the password.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2609474/2827296), it seems possible to read the contents without the password.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27508116/2827296) shows how to crack a document. (Thanks @TheFizh)

Comment: Also worth mentioning the password is crackable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project

Comment: Thanks for reply. Looks like keeping sensitive information in excel not secure after all.

Comment: If this helped, please mark it as accepted by pressing the checkmark next to the answer. Thanks!