# Unlock Excel 97-2003 Password Protected File

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection, password-encryption

I need help to access my old data from 2006 but I forgot the password to open.
I ran out of idea what kind of method I should use

I know how to unprotect sheet that is locked using vba, but this case is different, since the file has password to open (the file extension is .xls)

Any possible idea for this?
Thank you

Comment: Have you looked on here for any posts about cracking or unlocking passwords?

Comment: There is answer to your question here with usage of java or other API [Password Protected Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609301/password-protected-excel-file)

Comment: Hi @p77u77n77k, thank you for the information. But I'm still newbie, I don't understand at all also don't have all the tools
Is it possible for me to send the file I need to unlock and you help me unlocking it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ReynaldiKarundeng you can find free software to do that [How to crack remove xls password](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/how-to-remove-crack-or-break-a-forgotten-excel-xls-password/) I would recomend to use method described at "Other (Gathering Information)".

Comment: @p77u77n77k I already know that my file has password to open type of password from the step you show. but how to unlock it is still a problem